# Errors while removing packages

Tags: linux, ubuntu, installation, uninstall, package-management

I tried to remove packages using

```
sudo apt autoremove
```

But it shows the following error

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
2 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Setting up linux-image-4.4.0-128-generic (4.4.0-128.154) ...
Internal Error: Could not find image (/boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-128-generic)
dpkg: error processing package linux-image-4.4.0-128-generic (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 2
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of linux-image-extra-4.4.0-128-generic:
 linux-image-extra-4.4.0-128-generic depends on linux-image-4.4.0-128-generic; however:
  Package linux-image-4.4.0-128-generic is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package linux-image-extra-4.4.0-128-generic (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
                          Errors were encountered while processing:
 linux-image-4.4.0-128-generic
 linux-image-extra-4.4.0-128-generic
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

What is the error?

Answer (score 0):

I believe that the error is exactly as it seems; `dpkg` was somehow interrupted in the middle of its operations.

The way to fix that would be to run two commands: `sudo apt install -f` and `sudo dpkg  --configure -a` respectively to fix your problem.